# How PACKAGE argument for .External/.External2 works?

Tags: r

I have been exploring some `R` semantics and I am a bit puzzled how `PACKAGE` argument to `.External` interface works.

For example, for `rnorm` from `stats` package. With namespace lookup it works:

```
> rnorm
function (n, mean = 0, sd = 1) 
.External(C_rnorm, n, mean, sd)
<bytecode: 0x102874270>
<environment: namespace:stats>
> .External(stats:::C_rnorm, 10, 0, 1)
 [1] -0.2363370  0.9323128  0.9551952  0.2108897 -0.1170138  1.1439723  1.7838458  1.1358356  0.8431536  0.6363356
```

But if I try to use `PACKAGE` argument:

```
> .External("C_rnorm", 10, 0, 1, PACKAGE="stats")
Error in .External("C_rnorm", 10, 0, 1, PACKAGE = "stats") : 
  "C_rnorm" not available for .External() for package "stats"
> .External("rnorm", 10, 0, 1, PACKAGE="stats")
Error in .External("rnorm", 10, 0, 1, PACKAGE = "stats") : 
  "rnorm" not available for .External() for package "stats"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `rnorm` no longer uses `.External`. It was switched to `.Call` in the Subversion repository on 2014-07-09, so you likely have a bit of an older version of R. That said, I think (but do not know for certain) the problem is that the C code in stats does not allow dynamic lookup.

Comment: Also note that `stats:::C_rnorm` returns an "ExternalRoutine" object which has an address to the function. The function name isn't necessary "C_rnorm".